# How can I use NS-3 to simulate some routing algorithms?

Tags: networking, simulator, ns-3

I am trying to do a simulation for networking for some routing algorithms such as

OSPF, RIP, IS-IS, DSR

using NS3 ( network simulator 3) since it's free. But after reading the ns3-tutorial, I still have no clue where to start in order to simulate any of the above routing algorithms.
Any help will be very appreciated.

My understanding is, since in ns3 I have to create the nodes, channel, netDevices, and Application that will create the traffic. I think, since routing is done in the routers, that any thing related to what I want to do has to do with netDevices since routers are the devices that has to run the algorithm not the hosts (nodes) but where exactly I have to specify my own algorithm that I want to simulate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the routing examples provided with ns3. You can find those in the examples/routing directory of ns3. That should be a good starting point.